# How do I display a dropdown, options according to the values set in the useState? - React and Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state

So, I have an api which fetches the names of the celebrities, for time being I am just initializing the
state and storing the dummy data in the state:

```
const[drop,setDrop] = useState(["Virat Kohli","Selena Gomez","Deepika Padukone"]);
```

Now, I want my drop-down to have the following values:

1. Choose
2. Virat Kohli
3. Selena Gomez
4. Deepika Padukone

I have used the below code in the return function:

```
                   drop.map( d=> 
                            {
                                <MenuItem value={d} index="1">{d}</MenuItem>

                            })
```

But, nothing is displayed, also I am confused with the index part, it should iterate and increase.
Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: Your arrow function isn't returning the `<MenuItem>`. Add the `return` or remove the curly brackets: https://jsfiddle.net/fvd3wy9n/

Comment: Try this: `drop.map((drop) => (<MenuItem key={drop} value={drop}>{drop}</MenuItem>))
    );`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
drop.map( d=> { 
 <MenuItem value=`${d}` index="1">{d}</MenuItem>
})
```